# How to map procedural bricks on a Pyramid Part II

Tags: texturing

I created a pyramid from a default cube and applied uv unwrap > cube projection. That works great for a flat pyramid, but in the setup shown below, it gives distortion on the bottom and inner faces:

[image]

If I switch the Texture Coordinate from "UV" to "Object" I get a much better result, but then I have the problem of one face being horizontal bricks and one being vertical. This was originally solved by using cube project and UV but then, as I said, the inside and bottoms get distorted.

The question is how do I get a workable, procedural brick texture that matches up on all surfaces? And the goal is to have the main face of the pyramid all display horizontal bricks. Guidance greatly appreciated!

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tried the "select all faces, UV projection cube" on your pyramid, while using UV texture coordinates, and it all worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use the *Cube Projection* again.
*Select > All*
*UV > Cube Projection*

But to have more control, consider *unwrapping* your object using *manual seams*.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

One method: Go to UV editor, and mark proper seams, then orient each face to show the bricks lined up the way you want, while using UV texture coordinates.

Comment: That's good. I'll keep that in mind. Thanks!